# Show that the following matrix PSD over the interior of the d-dimensional simplex

Tags: linear-algebra

I would like to prove (or maybe disprove) that the following symmetric $d \times d$ matrix is PSD for all $p \in \Delta_d$  such that $p_i > 0$ for all $1 \leq i \leq d$ and $\sum_{i=1}^d p_i = 1$ (points in the interior of the $d$-dimensional simplex):
$$
M = \operatorname{diag} \left( \frac{1}{p} \right) + (u v^\top + vu^\top)
$$
where $u = \mathbf{1}_d$ is the all-ones vector and $v = \ln{\frac{1}{p}}$ (coordinate-wise). I've made simulations in high dimensions by which $M$ seems to be PSD. However I'm stuck at the formal proof.
I tried working with the definition of a PSD matrix and show that for all vectors $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$ it holds that $x^\top M x \geq 0$, and I got to the following identity:
$$
x^\top M x = \sum_{i=1}^d \frac{x_i^2}{p_i} +2 \left( \sum_{i=1}^d x_i \right) \cdot \left( \sum_{i=1}^d x_i \ln{\frac{1}{p_i}} \right)
$$
but I'm not sure how to proceed. Thanks!